# CodeIgniter need to get one row?

Tags: database, codeigniter

My query is

```
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

        $mobile=$row->mobileNo;
```

I need particular row1 mobileno,  but it getting all mobile numbers from db .....

Comment: use where condition to get that mobile number

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute this query to get first row from your table

```
$this->db->select('mobileNo');
$this->db->limit(1);
$result = $this->db->get('users')->result();

// This will return you single record
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I no need to print ..i like pass $mobile variable value to                              $url = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&sendername=".$sendername."&mobileno=".$mobile."&message=Hividya";

Comment: Its just for your reference that which value to access from returned result.
Then you can access the `$result` like `$result->mobileNo` depending on your returned result

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use more specific queries using limit 1, order by, where. Also you can use "[each](http://php.net/manual/es/function.each.php)" instead of foreach in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get('users')->row();
$mobile = $query->mobileNo;
```

Comment: $query = $this->db->get('users')->row(1);                                                                    its working getting first row value , i need last record , i mean last row when user registers that got place in last row

Comment: $query = $this->db->order_by('id DESC')->limit(1)->get('users')->row();